# How to get Shout from FourSquare?

Tags: asp.net, foursquare

I am using FourSquare API v2.
I am alrady getting CheckIn shouts from my friend list. But I want to get FourSquare CheckIn Shouts of non-friend using venue ID

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this due to Foursquare's privacy policies, which are in place to protect sensitive and personal information for its users.

Each shout is associated with a check-in, and the only way to get check-ins associated with a venue ID is through the [venues/herenow](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow) endpoint, which doesn't return you shouts for non-friends.